# What does VAO objects store in its attribute list?

Tags: c++, opengl

In OpenGL, does VAOs store VBO objects in its attribute list or does it store the data contained inside the VBO inside the attribute list?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object

> A Vertex Array Object (VAO) is an OpenGL Object that stores all of the state needed to supply vertex data (with one minor exception noted below). It stores the format of the vertex data as well as the Buffer Objects (see below) providing the vertex data arrays. **Note that VAOs do not copy, freeze or store the *contents* of the referenced buffers** - if you change any of the data in the buffers referenced by an existing VAO, those changes will be seen by users of the VAO.

(emphasis mine)